# Not showing images of Instagram in Approved Instagram Images tab in Magento1.9

Tags: magento-1.9, image, oauth, extensions

It has been set with "Client ID" and "Client Secret" and also "Redirect URI" in magento1.9 admin by registering API form in Instagram. After then it is be authenticated by clicking "Auth on Instagram" button from Admin->Configuration. It has been successfully authenticated. But it is not showing the images in Admin->Instagram->Approved Images page and also in product and also in Category page. I have set all things in Magento admin panel. I can't understand where I am wrong. And but, another thing is that in Instagram account page, it shows an warning message like "You have not authorized any applications to access your Instagram account."

Comment: https://magecomp.com/magento-instagram-connect.html Extension has been updated with Facebook Graph API, Old API's may not work anymore.